# How would one refer to "wage-theft" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

I think it's a relatively [new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wage_theft) and not universally shared concept. This is what I came up with:

> ladrón del salario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El enlace de [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wage_theft) de la pregunta original define el *wage-theft* como:

> **Wage theft** is the denial of wages or employee benefits rightfully owed an employee. It can be conducted by employers in various ways, among them failing to pay overtime; violating minimum-wage laws; the misclassification of employees as independent contractors, illegal deductions in pay; forcing employees to work "off the clock", or simply not paying an employee at all.

Este mismo artículo tiene su [**versión en español**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robo_de_salarios) en el que lo traduce como **robo de salarios**:

> El **robo de salarios** es la denegación del salario o de los complementos salariales debidos a un empleado. Las maneras más habituales de efectuar este robo son: no pagar las horas realmente trabajadas, no pagar las horas extra, no pagar el salario mínimo, no pagar según la categoría real del empleado, descuentos indebidos en la paga, obligar a trabajar fuera del horario acordado en el contrato, obligar a trabajar en vacaciones o en las pausas para la comida, o no pagar en absoluto.

En el mismo párrafo se aclara que

> Guarda una estrecha relación con el concepto más amplio de **explotación laboral**: todo robo de salarios es explotación laboral, pero no toda explotación laboral implica robo de salarios.

Answer (score 1):

I think we just use (in Spain at least) a generic adjective for that, such as ***caradura*** or *[**sinvergüenza**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y0M0uD4)*:

> Dicho de una persona: Que comete actos ilegales en provecho propio, o que incurre en inmoralidades.

So if you speak about a *empresario caradura* you can expect the kind of behaviour of a wage-thieve.

Comment: @RosieM.Banks dado que "robo de salarios" parece ser la respuesta correcta (o al menos una posibilidad más que adecuada) quizá podrías ponerla como una respuesta y la comunidad se encargará de validarla mediante votos.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "explotación laboral", since wage-theft reffers to the act of doing "explotación laboral" against your own employees